# Why can Object be actually Object[]?

Tags: java, arrays, object, reflection

I just came accross this behavior, as I wrote a dumpObject method using Reflection.

to reproduce:

```
public static class Tester {
        private String[] objects = new String[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println("testing Reflection");
        Tester tester = new Tester();
        Class<? extends Tester> class1 = tester.getClass();
        for (Field f : class1.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println(f);
            if (!f.isAccessible()) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }
            Object object = f.get(tester);
            System.out.println(object);
        }

    }
```

in this case, the object retrieved via `f.get(tester)` method is returning an array of String. If an Object can be actually an array, why is this illegal?

```
Object o = new String[]{"a", "b"};
```

Comment: What do you mean by illegal? `Object o = new String[]{"a", "b"};` is fine because an array is an Object.

Comment: `Object o = new String[]{"a", "b"};` is not illegal, it's perfectly valid code. Why would you want to do this is another matter.

Comment: Any array in Java is an `Object`.

Comment: oh sorry, I guess my Eclipse has fooled me. It shows it as error first, but after trying again, it seems valid...

Comment: @RafaelT You can look at the signature of `Arrays.deepToString` per example, taking an `Object[]` as parameter is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Java Tutorials. Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

> An *array* is a container **object** that...

From [Java Language Specification. Chapter 10. Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html):

> In the Java programming language, *arrays* are objects ([§4.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type `Object` ([§4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)). All methods of class `Object` may be invoked on an array.

In short, any array is an `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Object o = new String[]{"a", "b"};
```

Is perfectly legal java code:

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has
>   Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the
>   methods of this class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html